# Dynamic SQL, sp_executesql, and rebuilding the dynamic sql statement - Part 1

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

**Part 1:** In his article, "Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL...for SQL 2005 and Earlier", Erland Sommarskog gives an example of how to use dynamic sql with sp_executesql.

http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2005.html#sp_executesql

```
SELECT @sql =                                                  -- 19
'SELECT o.OrderID, o.OrderDate, od.UnitPrice, od.Quantity,     -- 20
        c.CustomerID, c.CompanyName, c.Address, c.City,        -- 21
        c.Region,  c.PostalCode, c.Country, c.Phone,           -- 22
        p.ProductID, p.ProductName, p.UnitsInStock,            -- 23
        p.UnitsOnOrder                                         -- 24
 FROM   dbo.Orders o                                           -- 25
 JOIN   dbo.[Order Details] od ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID       -- 26
 JOIN   dbo.Customers c ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID         -- 27
 JOIN   dbo.Products p ON p.ProductID = od.ProductID           -- 28
     WHERE  1 = 1'                                             -- 29
                                                               -- 30
IF @orderid IS NOT NULL                                        -- 31
   SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND o.OrderID = @xorderid' +         -- 32
                        ' AND od.OrderID = @xorderid'          -- 33
                                                               -- 34
IF @fromdate IS NOT NULL                                       -- 35
   SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND o.OrderDate >= @xfromdate'       -- 36
```

etc...

So, as you build your dynamic sql statement, it makes sense if you have to run just one sp_executesql for your `@sql` variable.

However, let's suppose you've built your `@sql`, and returned the filtered records you want returned, but you also want a `COUNT` of the records returned.

What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Would you have to declare another variable, `@sql_2`, whose build would be nearly identical to `@sql`, except the `SELECT` statement in `@sql_2` would do a `SELECT COUNT(*)...` instead of a `SELECT  col1, col2, col3`?

Or is there a better approach to take?

Comment: since you are returning the records, why don't you just do count on them after retrial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String the SQL statements together separated by semicolons.  Here is a working example that returns the tables in your database that start with the letter "A" and the count.
First the simple version.  This returns 2 result sets, the second one being the count.

```
declare @findTables nvarchar(256)
set @findTables = N'A%'

declare @sql nvarchar(max)

set @sql = N'set nocount on; '+
'select * from sys.tables where name like '''+@findTables+''';'+
'select @@RowCount as [RowCount];';

execute sp_executesql @sql
```

Now a version where a variable gets valued with the count for when you need to use it later in the stored proc.

```
declare @findTables nvarchar(256)
set @findTables = N'A%'

declare @sql nvarchar(max)
declare @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);
declare @rowCount int

set @sql = N'set nocount on; 
select * from sys.tables where name like @findTablesParm;
select @rowCountParm = @@rowcount;
select @rowCountParm as [RowCount];';

SET @ParmDefinition = N'@findTablesParm nvarchar(256), 
    @rowCountParm int OUTPUT';

execute sp_executesql @sql, 
    @ParmDefinition, 
    @findTablesParm=@findTables, 
    @rowCountParm=@rowCount OUTPUT
```

After this runs you should see 2 result sets, the second one will contain the RowCount and the variable @rowCount will also contain the row count.